# Bulk updates to SharePoint Lists

Tags: list, caml-query, content, bulk

I was recently assigned to make changes to several SharePoint lists that store content for a public facing web site.

Due to the SharePoint settings or my VM’s Internet Explorer settings I could not use the datasheet mode. I had to literally find each item, click edit and update the data manually. My updates were mostly just replacing a word with another word.

It got really boring and annoying and made me start thinking there must be an automated way to do this. Sure If I had access to the datasheet mode I could have copied the column to an excel sheet do a find/replace and paste all back to SharePoint list. Still not fully automated and requires back and forth operations between Excel and SharePoint.

There are some small open source tools but they all do a different set of things. Like adding event listeners to the list, viewing/managing columns etc..

I am looking for a similar tool with the famous U2U. Instead of creating CAML queries to bring back data I should be able to generate update queries and have an option to run it against the list.

Any recommendations? 
The version I will be using is 2007 but the tool/solution must support 2010 and 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about to create small console share point application?

you can use this info to do that:

http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/01/20/sharepoint-using-batch-updates-to-speed-up-performance/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc404818%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: yeah - better would do a windows forms app for better user experience. I was looking to see if there is one built already...